# Does Google Cloud App Engine support websocket applications?

Tags: javascript, go, google-cloud-platform, websocket, react-fullstack

I deployed my backend server on google cloud engine and it generated an https. I am unable to use this with Websocket javascript library at frontend (react) and generates the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'https' is not allowed.
```

Please tell me if there is a workaround.

- https link generated from google cloud engine where my golang backend server is: 'https://project-name'
- websocket currently being initialized by:

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/ws');

Comment: That does not work because the backend server is deployed at 'https://project-name' only. 'wss://project-name' would be non-existent.

Comment: Use `var socket = new WebSocket('wss://project-name/ws');` to connect to the websocket endpoint `/ws` on the server `https://project-name`.

Comment: Is it Compute Engine or App Engine?

Comment: Sorry, I understood with the URL provided!! It's App Engine. WebSocket is not supported on App Engine, use Cloud RUn instead.